# Alternate to sumproduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Does anyone know a more efficient way to write this? I seem to be having quite a bit of issues with excel giving me "not enough system resources" because I have about 30 slightly varied versions of this in my excel spread sheet.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!B2:B1000="Human Resources")*(Data!E2:E1000<>"Resolved")*(Data!E2:E1000<>"Closed")*(Data!E2:E1000<>"Cancelled"))
```

I have looked into countifs but I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: Try replacing the asterisks (*) in the formula with commas (,).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is something like this (note the spacing is exaggerated between the ranges for emphasis, remove for actual use):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!B2:B1000="Human Resources") * (Data!E2:E1000<>"Closed") , (Data!B2:B1000="Human Resources") * (Data!E2:E1000<>"Cancelled" ) , (Data!B2:B1000="Human Resources") * (Data!E2:E1000<>"Resolved" ))
```

Test Data:

- Human Resources  Resolved
- Human Resources  Closed
- Human Resources  Cancelled
- *Human Resources Open*
- *Human Resources Yellow*
- *Human Resources Duck*
- *Human Resources Rock*
- Human Resources  Resolved
- Human Resources  Closed
- Human Resources  Cancelled
- Parks and Rec    3

Expected: 4

Result: 4

I tried the same formula, changing the references to point to the larger local set, with a random sample of 1000 rows and there was no noticeable slow down or warning.  By no means is it bench-marked or optimized, but the intent is left pretty clear.

Larger data sets might cause your machine to run out of available indexes or raw memory, and if you suspect that is the case, partition the data set and do a chunk at a time (perhaps try first splitting it in half attempting 500 rows at once), summing each chunk after all chunks are done.

One last note, for posterity, SUMPRODUCT is fairly version dependent.  If you run into problems, you can change it to a strictly SUM formula, with just a bit more work.

Answer (score 3):

`COUNTIFS` should do the job, like this

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"Human Resources",E:E,"<>Resolved",E:E,"<>Closed",E:E,"<>Cancelled")
```

Comment: Any way to do something like this?     =COUNTIFS(B:B,"Human Resources",E:E,{"<>Resolved","<>Closed","<>Cancelled"}) I googled it for a few hours and couldn't find much. I figured it would be less resourse intensive then it looking through E:E multiple times